# How do you handle viewport resize when android softkeyboard pops up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two scenarios were i want to make this work just like it does on iOS (where the elements stay the same size). first can be found on

[Contact El Paso Texas Graphic Designer and Web Designer | Desert Sun Studio](https://www.desertsunstudio.com/contact-desert-sun-studio-website-developer-designer-texas-southwest-united-states)

where i have this js to set to viewport to fixed px

```
setTimeout(function() {

var $viewheight = $(window).height();
var $viewwidth = $(window).width();
var $viewport = $("meta[name=viewport]");

$viewport.attr('content', 'height=' + $viewheight +'px, width =' + $viewwidth + 'px, initial-scale=1.0, user- 
scalable=no');

}, 300);
```

which half works as it doesnt resize the content but covers half the page without being able to scroll

then you can see at

https://www.desertsunstudio.com/contact

this fix does not do anything and 'squishes' the layout because it is in a percent grid

i tried stackoverflow but there wasnt much documented...if anyone has a solution your help would be greatly appreciated!